# Symfony component caching

Tags: php, caching, symfony-1.4

I turn on caching the component by editing cache.yml file in my module

```
_startpage:
  enabled: true
  contextual: true
  lifetime: 60
```

There was no time difference after that but I think the component is cached because there is a symfony cache box over it (With cache info). I realized that the number of queries to DB is the same as without caching - component for sure execute some queries so why the number of queries did not changed?

Comment: Just spitballing here.. You're in production and have cleared cache when testing, right?

Comment: Can we see the component, the partial and the template which include the partial?

Comment: @Mike I test on dev environment with Cache turned on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

factories.yml

```
view_cache:
  class: sfFileCache
  param:
    automatic_cleaning_factor: 0
    cache_dir:                 %SF_TEMPLATE_CACHE_DIR%
    lifetime:                  86400
    prefix:                    %SF_APP_DIR%/template
```